# Adding curves to the ends of a UIBezierPath(arcCentre)

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following code added in the drawRect function of a UIView creating the following attached green arc.

Is there a way I can make the edges at the ends of the curve to look like the red arc rounded edges in the smaller image attached.

```
[![//Draw the Interior
        let center = CGPoint(x: bounds.width/2,
            y: bounds.height/2)

        //Calculate the radius based on the max dimension of the view.
        let radius = max(bounds.width, bounds.height)

        //Thickness of the Arc
        let arcWidth: CGFloat = 76

        //Start and End of Circle angle
        let startAngle: CGFloat = 3 * π/4
        let endAngle: CGFloat = π/4

        let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: radius/2 - arcWidth/2,
            startAngle: startAngle,
            endAngle: endAngle,
            clockwise: true)

        path.lineWidth  = arcWidth
        counterColor.setStroke()
        path.stroke()]
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the [`lineCapStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBezierPath_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIBezierPath/lineCapStyle) property of the bezier path to 
`.Round`:

> A line with a rounded end. Quartz draws the line to extend beyond the
>   endpoint of the path. The line ends with a semicircular arc with a
>   radius of 1/2 the line’s width, centered on the endpoint.

```
path.lineCapStyle = .Round
```

Comment: Is it this way: path.lineCapStyle = kCGLineCapRound As I am getting an error - use of unresolved identifier.

Comment: @Gugulethu: My fault, it is just `.Round` in Swift.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Worked perfectly. ;)